# Can I access the geoNear functionality of mongo via the ruby driver?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, geolocation

I'm retrieving results from mongo based on a geo query using the ruby driver.
I'd like the results to be returned with their respective distances.
That facility is available at the shell using geoNear command:

```
db.runCommand( { geoNear : "places", near : [50,50], num : 10 } );
```

How do I do this via the ruby API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

where `db` is the connection to your db you can use `#command` :

```
  db.command({'geoNear' => "places", 'near'=>[50,50], 'num' => 10})
```

This has to be an `OrderedHash` in ruby 1.8, hashes are ordered in 1.9 so you are all good with default hash if using 1.9