# Using mongomapper to execute server runCommand geoNear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I would very much like to use the mongo geoNear command as discussed [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-MultilocationDocuments).

Here is the command I entered in my rails console with the accompanying error message.

```
MongoMapper.database.command({ 'geoNear' => "trips", 'near' => [45,45]})
Mongo::OperationFailure: Database command 'geoNear' failed: 
  (errmsg: 'more than 1 geo indexes :('; ok: '0.0').
```

I can not make sense of the error message, it is supposedly impossible to have more than 1 geo index and I am certain that I have only created one.

Based on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306241/can-i-access-the-geonear-functionality-of-mongo-via-the-ruby-driver) I believe I am wording the query correctly. Does anyone understand that error message? How would I go about destroying and recreating my indexes?

I am using rails 3.1 with mongodb v2.0 and the mongo ruby gem v1.5.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really asked this too soon, maybe I should delete it? Somehow there were in fact too many geo indexes, because deleting the index and recreating it fixed the problem.

```
MongoMapper.database.collection('trips').drop_indexes
Trip.ensure_index [[:route, '2d']]
```

Comment: Or you can accept your answer and thus gaining you the self-learner badge. lol. :D

Comment: @NoICE: self-learner: "Answered your own question with score of 3 or more".

Comment: @muistooshort yes. That's what I ment. (Of course you cannot accept your own answer without any votes. Thanks for clarifying that.)